# How to rotate label of hAxis using google-chart- deprecated url using google chart GET Method

Tags: google-visualization

It is possible to rotate hAxis by using this
 hAxis: {
        direction:-1,
        slantedText:true,
        slantedTextAngle:45
      // here you can even use 180
    }

How to rotate label "Low| Midium |high" using  url

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=720x410&chd=t:220,35,20&chxr=1,0,100&chds=0,220&chxt=x,y,x&chbh=45,0,10&chxl=0:|High|Medium|Low|2:||Task+Priority||&